# dart.global.firebase.storage is null

Tags: firebase, angular-dart

I initialize firebase in the main method as such

void main() {

```
  fb.initializeApp(
      apiKey: "123",
      authDomain: "123",
      databaseURL: "123",
      projectId: "123",
      storageBucket: "123",
      messagingSenderId: "123");

  runApp(ng.AppComponentNgFactory, createInjector: injector);
}
```

Then in a component, I import firebase:

```
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;
```

Finally I try to use storage:

```
fb.storage();
```

But, I'm getting a null pointer:

```
EXCEPTION: NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.storage'
STACKTRACE: 
packages/firebase/src/top_level.ddc.js 64:100                                       storage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the firebase dart package documentation it looks like you need to add an additional script if you want to use storage.

See: https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase/latest/#do-you-need-to-use-firestore